# bash generate random number, but checking file if the number has already been chosen

Tags: bash

I'm trying to generate a random number with bash, but it has to be unique. So I want to save the generated number in a file, and every time it generates a number it must grab the file and check if the number has already been generated.

This is what I have to generate the number:

```
function _generateNumber
{
   echo -e "\e[32m Setting node port\e[0m"

   NUM=$(shuf -i 3000-3999 -n 1)

   echo -e "\e[32m Generated: ${NUM} \e[0m"
   portsDir=/inc/ports.txt

   if grep -Fxq "$portsDir"
   then
       echo -e "\e[32m I found the directory \e[0m"
       if [ -f "$portsDir" ]
       then
           echo -e "\e[32m I have not found the code yet \e[0m"
           echo "$NUM" > "$portsDir"
       fi
       echo $NUM
   else
       echo -e "\e[32m I have found the code, generate a new one \e[0m"
       _generateNumber
   fi
}

node_port=$(_generateNumber)
```

I created the /inc/ports.txt file, but nothing is written into it, also the echo is empty and not showing a value in it.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think this is an appropriate use of recursion. Just use a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I understood the question wrong, but it seems you only need to check whether the generated number has been generated before. If not, add it to the file.
Try the following:

```
function _generateNumber
{
  NUM=$(shuf -i 3000-3999 -n 1)
  portsDir=/inc/ports.txt

  found=`grep -cx $NUM $portsDir`
  if [ $found -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $NUM >> $portsDir
    echo $NUM
  else
    _generateNumber
  fi
}
```

Please note the `>>` when redirecting the number into the file.

Comment: This does not work either, I added some echo's to see where it failed, but they are never echo'd back to me.

Comment: The problem is within the exit code of <code>grep</code>. I updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I agree with ccarton: "I don't think this is an appropriate use of recursion. Just use a while loop"

Comment: I agree aswell, didn't yet have it since I was first experiencing this problem. Now I know what was wrong, and can indeed make a while loop of it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach to add photos to a randomised slideshow, where I generate random numbers to provide the position in the slide show. I need to ensure that the random numbers generated for the new photos haven't been previously used. Here's my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
PortsFile=/inc/ports.txt
min=1;max=5 # Port range. Change these to 3000 and 3999 respectively
create_random () {
        num=$(($min + RANDOM % $max))
}
range=$(($max - $min));((range++));used=$(wc -l < $PortsFile) # Get range and used ports
[[ $used -eq $range ]] && { echo "All available ports used. Aborting.";exit 0; }
while true; do create_random
[[ $(grep $num $PortsFile) ]] || { echo $num>>$PortsFile; break; }; done
```

The variables min and max are the highest and lowest port numbers that you want to use, and a check also follows to ensure that all the ports in the chosen range have not already been taken. This is done by comparing the range that has been selected from variables `min` and `max` (producing the variable `range`) and the number of ports that have already been used (variable `used`).

**Note:** If you are going to use this for 1000 ports, and 999 of them are used, there will obviously be a considerable delay running the loop where a random number is needed that matches the only available free port number. This is OK for 10 ports as the delay is acceptable but it may not be for 1000 ports. Why not use sequential port numbers instead?

Comment: Reason being is that we give a specific range of ports to certain instances. It's a cluster, and per project we have 1 node, so 1000 projects can be created, which will likely not happen any time soon. When it does, we can easily say we'd increase the max range.